# Should I have a different admin? method for the view and for the before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I'm learning Rails and working on [DinnerDash](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/dinner_dash.html).

In `application_controller.rb` I have:

```
helper_method :admin?
def admin?
  current_user.admin_code == 'secret' if current_user
end
```

So I could use `if admin?` in my view files to display certain things only to admins. Now I want to write a before_filter that checks if the `current_user` is an admin and if not, redirects.

It seems to me that I have to write another method to do this. For view files, I want the method to return false if the user isn't an admin, and for the `before_filter`, I want it to redirect.

Still, something tells me that this isn't the most efficient way to do this. Since I'm learning Rails, I don't want to develop any bad habits of writing code that isn't DRY. Any ideas on how to best handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make `admin?` an instance method of the User model. I think it belongs there because you're actually asking for information about a user object.

Then, for the before_filter, I would do something like this:

```
before_filter :admin_or_redirect

def admin_or_redirect
  redirect_to some_url if !current_user.admin?
end
```

Then you can still call `admin?` in your views on @user (which you assign current_user to in your controller), and have a different behavior for your before_filter.

**EDIT:**

You also want to change your `admin?` method like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def admin?
    self.admin_code == 'secret'
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that `admin?` should be part of the `User` model? It's checking `current_user` and `current_user` is checking the `sessions` hash.

Comment: See my edit on how to change the `admin?` method into an instance method.

Comment: By the way, the reason it makes more sense to put the `admin?` method into the model is because it's business logic. Your controllers should not have to know about how the admin functionality is implemented (with `admin_code == "secret"`). They should simply ask the model, "is this user an admin?" and the model should respond with yes or no. Remember that the controller is simply the middle-man between view and model. The only processing it should do is with session parameters and browser redirects. This isn't a set-in-stone rule but following it will save you a lot of headache as you go.